# How to reduce a 3d data sets to a 2d data sets for multivariate modeling

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have many batches of biological data, and each of batch is in 2D form with different variables (columns) and time points (rows). Below is an example:

```
Batch1  VA  VB  VC
Day1    2   4   6
Day2    33  23  12
Day3    124 223 432
```

And I also have a data set that displays each batch's quality with different quality numbers (as columns):

```
Batch   QA      QB      QC
Batch1  0.40    0.22    0.72
Batch2  0.85    0.76    0.18
Batch3  0.38    0.15    0.15
```

We can assume the above data sets give us some sort of 3D data. The intention is to do multivariate analysis to build models on all these batches for prediction of quality.

I am able to transform the batch data sets (using unpivot) as seen below so each row represents a batch. Then, I am thinking of adding columns to the table for quality numbers so I can model the quality against the variables.

```
Day1    Day1    Day1    Day2    Day2    Day2    Day3    Day3    Day3
VA      VB      VC      VA      VB      VC      VA      VB      VC
2       4       6       33      23      12      124     223     432
```

The fact is now I have a table with two rows of header (time and variables) for all the time series variables. My question is if there is an alternative way that could let me start modeling without so many data transformation steps (or at least save me some steps)? If not, is there any suggestion to compress the two rows of header to one row? I am looking into the `python`/`pandas` solution now,  but anything else (like `R`) is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pandas you can read your first file like this:

```
df = pd.read_table('t.txt', delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
```

It gives you a DataFrame:

```
         VA   VB   VC
Batch1               
Day1      2    4    6
Day2     33   23   12
Day3    124  223  432
```

Then `sr = df.unstack()` gives you a series with a MultiIndex:

```
    Batch1
VA  Day1        2
    Day2       33
    Day3      124
VB  Day1        4
    Day2       23
    Day3      223
VC  Day1        6
    Day2       12
    Day3      432
```

Then concatenate the index strings (adjust to taste):

```
sr.index = sr.index.get_level_values(0) + '_' + sr.index.get_level_values(1)
```

Now you have:

```
VA_Day1      2
VA_Day2     33
VA_Day3    124
VB_Day1      4
VB_Day2     23
VB_Day3    223
VC_Day1      6
VC_Day2     12
VC_Day3    432
```

If you prefer the sort order to be days first (as in your question), do `sr = df.T.unstack()` instead of `sr = df.unstack()`.

Comment: Thank you John for the solution, which is very helpful. I feel I can repeat the steps to have my batch data processed. But just curious, Is there a batch process to get many tables (e.g., batch1, batch2, etc.) transformed and merge them together so that I have a table in which each row (or column) is a batch. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexXu: Probably you want `pd.concat()` to concatenate all DataFrames or Series in a list, or perhaps the DataFrame constructor which accepts a list or dict of Series.